# SqlException when publishing website to Azure

Tags: azure, azure-sql-database, sqlexception

I just published my website to Azure. When the website opens in the browser, I get this this error:

```
System.Data.SqlClient.SqlException: Invalid object name 'dbo.Gebruikers'
```

In visual studio the website is using local database, but how can I connect an Azure SQL database to the website?

Stack trace:

```
[SqlException (0x80131904): Invalid object name 'dbo.Gebruikers'.]
System.Data.SqlClient.SqlConnection.OnError(SqlException exception, Boolean   breakConnection, Action`1 wrapCloseInAction) +1787814
System.Data.SqlClient.SqlInternalConnection.OnError(SqlException exception,  Boolean breakConnection, Action`1 wrapCloseInAction) +5341674
System.Data.SqlClient.TdsParser.ThrowExceptionAndWarning(TdsParserStateObject stateObj, Boolean callerHasConnectionLock, Boolean asyncClose) +546
System.Data.SqlClient.TdsParser.TryRun(RunBehavior runBehavior, SqlCommand  cmdHandler, SqlDataReader dataStream, BulkCopySimpleResultSet bulkCopyHandler,  TdsParserStateObject stateObj, Boolean& dataReady) +1693
System.Data.SqlClient.SqlDataReader.TryConsumeMetaData() +61
System.Data.SqlClient.SqlDataReader.get_MetaData() +90
System.Data.SqlClient.SqlCommand.FinishExecuteReader(SqlDataReader ds,  RunBehavior runBehavior, String resetOptionsString) +377
System.Data.SqlClient.SqlCommand.RunExecuteReaderTds(CommandBehavior cmdBehavior, RunBehavior runBehavior, Boolean returnStream, Boolean async, Int32 timeout, Task& task, Boolean asyncWrite, SqlDataReader ds) +1421
System.Data.SqlClient.SqlCommand.RunExecuteReader(CommandBehavior cmdBehavior, RunBehavior runBehavior, Boolean returnStream, String method, TaskCompletionSource`1 completion, Int32 timeout, Task& task, Boolean asyncWrite) +177
System.Data.SqlClient.SqlCommand.RunExecuteReader(CommandBehavior cmdBehavior, RunBehavior runBehavior, Boolean returnStream, String method) +53
System.Data.SqlClient.SqlCommand.ExecuteReader(CommandBehavior behavior, String method) +137
System.Data.SqlClient.SqlCommand.ExecuteDbDataReader(CommandBehavior behavior) +41
System.Data.Common.DbCommand.ExecuteReader(CommandBehavior behavior) +10
System.Data.EntityClient.EntityCommandDefinition.ExecuteStoreCommands(EntityCommand entityCommand, CommandBehavior behavior) +427
```

Comment: Does the table exist ? And where is your related codes?

Comment: What does your connection string inside the `web.config` look like?  Are you connecting to an SQL Azure database?  Depending on how you publish, you can either set the connection string via the Azure portal, or use a config transform during the publish process.

Comment: @BrendanGreen How can I connect to an Azure database using the connection string?

Comment: With SQL Server Management Studio (express).